# Chant Argentina fans are singing

Tags: argentina, deportes, letras-de-canciones

https://youtu.be/0tkDIP6O56Y?t=29m54s

The fans start singing some chant, and they continue to do so till [00:31:20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tkDIP6O56Y&feature=youtu.be&t=31m20s). I have tried to go through all the Argentina chants I could find on YouTube, but none seemed to match.

I believe I have heard this song also sung by football fans in the World Cup in the Argentina - Nigeria match played on Tuesday the 26th of June, somewhere around the 89th minute (but I am not really sure if it is the same song).

Can someone help me identify this chant, please?

Comment: is your link correct/ The ole ola thing is everywhere in Spanish. It is not a song, it's a chant.

Comment: Question topic corrected to chant. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's a song that is adapted by soccer fans to a lot of clubs / nations, etc. You will hear it in other countries such as Perú. One version could be:

> Ole, ole, ole,
>   Ole, ole, ole, ola,
>   Ole, ole, ole,
>   Cada día te quiero más,
>   Soy Argentino,
>   Es un sentimiento,
>   No puedo parar...
>   (Se Repite...)
>
> - [*Argentina es un sentimiento*](https://www.fanchants.com/football-songs/argentina-chants/lo-argentina/)

As you can see soccer fans of other countries also use it (Perú):

- [LETRA CADA DÍA TE QUIERO MÁS (Alianza Lima club Perú)](https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=1207140)

I'm not sure this question belongs in Spanish SE. Maybe music or sports.

Comment: It's used in concerts too (foo fighters in this case) https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GZFlKyV-m-8 Sometimes the bands even plays the base rhythm